# Generating client library and JavaDoc with JAX-WS RI

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am implementing a new web service using JAX-WS RI and am trying to figure out the best way to go about building my client library and autogenerating the API documentation.

Say I have an endpoint implementation (com.mysite.webservice.MyServiceEndpoint) as follows:

```
  @WebService(serviceName = "MyService", endpointInterface = "com.mysite.webservice.MyService")
  public class MyServiceEndpoint implements MyService
  {
    public void myMethod(final com.mysite.webservice.spec.MyObject blah) {
      //Do Something
    }
  }
```

and the referenced interface (com.mysite.webservice.MyService):

```
  @WebService
  public interface MyService {
    public void myMethod(final MyObject blah);
  }
```

I am currently able to generate a working client during my ant build by running `wsgen` to generate the WSDL and then using that WSDL file I run `wsimport` to generate the client files. This all functions fine, except for when I run JavaDoc on the generated client files I obviously get none of my documentation that was defined on the interface, or my specification objects being passed into the method call. Instead I generate the documentation directly from the interface and specification objects that I wrote by hand and have JavaDoc for. The problem I am having is that it the autogenerated objects are in a different package than the ones I defined. (`com.mysite.webservice instead` of `com.mysite.webservice.spec`).

So, two questions...

1) Is there a way to specify what package my autogenerated objects will be placed into?

2) Is this the best approach to building the client/generating documentation or am I overlooking a better way that can be done with JAX-WS RI?

3) Is it possible to generate client classes directly from the Java SEI (Service Endpoint Implementation) and associated server-side classes rather than from the WSDL.